# MVC 3 Razor - Trigger validation from controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor

I have to check to see if the new users email already exists in the database.  The email passes all the normal validation but what if I want to trigger a special validation from the controller if the email already exists after checking it against the database?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In controller:
`ModelState.AddModelError("ErrorEmail", "Error Message");`

In View:
`@Html.ValidationMessage("ErrorEmail")`

Hope this helps

Comment: There is actually a way to accomplish this from the ViewModel itself.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for is the [`RemoteAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.remoteattribute%28v=vs.98%29.aspx).

This is a ValidationAttribute for remote validation.  It works like the other validation attributes by adding model errors to your modelstate dictionary.

Check out these articles on using the `RemoteAttribute`:

- http://deanhume.com/Home/BlogPost/mvc-3-and-remote-validation/51
- http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2011/01/04/ASPNETMVC3RemoteValidationTutorial.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to perform conditional validation from the ViewModel.  The VM class will need to implement the IValidatableObject interface.

Then add a method similar to this at the bottom of the VM:

```
    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (validationContext == null)
            return null;

        var valResults = new List<ValidationResult>();

        if (!EmailExists))
            valResults.Add(new ValidationResult($"Email is required.", new[] { "ErrorEmail" }));

        return valResults;
    }
```

And of course you will need this in the View:

```
@Html.ValidationMessage("ErrorEmail")
```

Hope that helps!