# Setting fields to conditionally use required field validator

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, web-applications

I have a radio button with 2 options, when 1 is selected I want to require 5 text boxes to be filled out, when 2 is selected those text boxes don't have to be. I'm using C# code behind in asp.net and so far I'm utilizing the asp requiredfieldvalidators on my required fields. But I'm needing help in setting the logic to handle this request. I've got a background in C but scripting is still pretty foreign to me so if there is a solution there please let me know! Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655415/conditional-validation-for-viewmodel-fields-on-asp-mvc for some suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use a CustomValidator - that even gives you the choice to validate client site (java script) or server side (code behind)

Sample ClientSide validation ASPX:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btncbValid" Text="Test" ValidationGroup="vg1" />
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cvValidator"  ValidationGroup="vg1" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Error!"
ClientValidationFunction="validateMethod"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

JS:

```
function validateMethod(sender, args) {
var txt1 = document.getElementById("<%= tb1.ClientID %>");
var txt2 = document.getElementById("<%= tb2.ClientID %>");
var txt3 = document.getElementById("<%= tb3.ClientID %>");
var txt4 = document.getElementById("<%= tb4.ClientID %>");
var txt5 = document.getElementById("<%= tb5.ClientID %>");

var rb1 = document.getElementById('<%= rb1.ClientID %>');
var rb2 = document.getElementById('<%= rb2.ClientID %>');

args.IsValid = 
(
(rb1.checked && txt1.value != "" && txt2.value != "" && txt3.value != "" && txt4.value != "" && txt5.value != "" )
||
(rb2.checked && txt1.value == "" && txt2.value == "" && txt3.value == "" && txt4.value == "" && txt5.value == "" )
)
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, I'm going to plug it in and start testing. Thank you very much!

Comment: haven't tested the code but the approach should be the right one

Comment: So my app is a form with a bunch of data entry and a submit button that parses the data into an email. So where does this custom validator get called so that it happens client side? Do I need to call it on a radio button event or something?

Comment: `<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rdoOriginal">
<asp:ListItem Value="0">Original is already at Copy Center</asp:ListItem> 
<asp:ListItem Value="1">Original to be copied is attached</asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>`

 So I have a radio button list with 2 list items, and it looks like in your example you are checking checked status. How do I check for the list item value and handle that? edit: I have no idea how you embed blocks of code like that or I'd make it clean for you

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/308301/reading-the-selected-value-from-aspradiobuttonlist-using-jquery